# Cypress Error making HTTP POST with File in request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cypress

I upgraded from Cypress 6.8.0 to 7.0.1. After the upgrade, when this function is called by one of the Cypress tests

```
async saveTask (task, file) {
  const requestBody = new FormData()
  requestBody.append('file', file)

  return await http.post('/api/endpoint', requestBody, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
},
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: 
The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type number (45)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:696:11)
    at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:661:15)
    at Request.write (/Users/donal/Library/Caches/Cypress/7.0.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/request/request.js:1496:27)
    at /Users/donal/Library/Caches/Cypress/7.0.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/request/request.js:546:20
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>:null:null)
    at end (/Users/donal/Library/Caches/Cypress/7.0.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/request/request.js:545:23)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/donal/Library/Caches/Cypress/7.0.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/request/request.js:578:7)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

The `http` object that I use to make the POST request is an Axios instance and the `file` object that I append to the request body is a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). The file object is the cause of the problem, because if I don't append it to the request body, the error doesn't occur.

The error only occurs when the function is run by a Cypress test. Cypress uses Node.js, and judging by the error message above it seems the `File` type is not allowed. Furthermore, the [Axios request config docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) indicate that when Axios runs under Node, a `File` is not allowed.

```
  // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
  // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'
  // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
  // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
  // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
  // - Node only: Stream, Buffer
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred'
  },
```

So I guess I need to convert the `File` objects to *something else*, so that this function will work both within the app itself, and when run by Cypress.

On the server-side (a Spring Boot app), this file is bound to a `MultipartFile`

```
public void handlePost(
    RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {

    // controller action body       
}
```

If my theory that the `File` type is the problem, what should I use instead and how should I do the conversion?

Comment: It looks like this issue [Bug: cy.intercept POST terminates cypress process #15901](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/15901#event-4576204020)

Comment: you can put this in your form `<form role="form" id="sampleForm" action="/post/url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 2):

> The error only occurs when the function is run by a Cypress test.
> Cypress uses Node.js, and judging by the error message above it seems
> the File type is not allowed. Furthermore, the Axios request config
> docs indicate that when Axios runs under Node, a File is not allowed.

By default `Cypress` starts `Electron` in headless mode, i.e. the tests would always have access to browser APIs. You can control on which browser you want to run the tests. More details [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Electron-Browser).

> Now let's look at the solution for file upload

Assuming the `file` you are referring in the function `saveTask` is an `input` field of `type=file` and `name=file`.

And let's say, you need to upload a png image named `email.png` which is at `cypress/fixtures/images/email.png`.

Use the following block of code for uploading the file.

```
 cy.fixture('images/email.png').as('emailImage')
   cy.get('input[name=file]').then(function (el) {
     const blob = Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(this.emailImage, 'image/png')
     const file = new File([blob], 'email.png', { type: 'image/png' })
     const list = new DataTransfer()
     list.items.add(file)
     el[0].files = list.files
     el[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }))
 })
```

Now you can trigger the action based on which your upload api (/api/endpoint) is invoked and finally verify the upload is successful.

```
 // Trigger the action which causes the upload api to be invoked e.g. clicking on a button
 cy.get('input[type=button]').click();
 
 // Verify the api invocation is successful (The below code checks a div with id result to have the String 'Success')
 cy.get('#result').should('contain', 'Success');
```

You can upload any type of file and it doesn't have to be an image. For more information look at [fixture](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture) and [Blob](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/blob). This answer is based on this [example](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/blob#Using-an-image-fixture-for-upload) on Blob documentation.

This repo runs a test on CI using GitHub Actions https://github.com/GSSwain/file-upload-cypress-test and the server is a Spring boot app (Run as a Docker container on CI server) code is at https://github.com/GSSwain/file-upload-ajax-sample

Comment: Do you know if this works in Cypress 7.X?

Comment: It does work with Cypress 7.X. I tested with  "version": "7.0.1".

Comment: This repo runs a test on CI using GitHub Actions https://github.com/GSSwain/file-upload-cypress-test and the server is a Spring boot app (Run as a Docker container on CI server) code is at
https://github.com/GSSwain/file-upload-ajax-sample