# Cypress crashes with some error INVALID ARG TYPE

Tags: cypress

after update tp cypress 7.0.1 I get the following error when running cypress:

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type number (45)

can someone help me with that?

Comment: Are you using `cy.intercept()` with POST method in your test ?

Comment: Yes, I use this in some test cases. Is there some problem with this?

Comment: Yes there is an open bug for this for 7.0.1 - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/15901#event-4576204020. Please comment out the cy.intercept to check if you are getting the same errors or not.

Comment: OK, thank you. I am going to try what you suggest.

Comment: getting the same issue. you can also follow this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023339/error-making-http-post-with-file-in-request-body